# Return Struct from Function in C

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm very new to langage C and I need to make a lot of matrix calculation and I decided to use a matrix struct.

Matrix.h

```
struct Matrix
{
    unsigned int nbreColumns;
    unsigned int nbreRows;
    double** matrix;
};

struct Matrix CreateNewMatrix(unsigned int n,unsigned int m);
double GetMatrixValue(struct Matrix* m,unsigned int ligne,unsigned int colonne);
```

Matrix.c

```
#include "matrix.h"

struct Matrix CreateNewMatrix(unsigned int n,unsigned int m){
    struct Matrix mat;
    mat.nbreColumns = n;
    mat.nbreRows = m;
    mat.matrix = (double**)malloc(n * sizeof(double*));

    unsigned int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mat.matrix[i] = (double*)calloc(m,sizeof(double));
    }

    return mat;
}

double GetMatrixValue(struct Matrix* m,unsigned int ligne,unsigned int colonne){
    return m->matrix[ligne][colonne];
}
```

Then I compile, no errors ...

I made a few tests :

Main.c

```
struct Matrix* m1 = CreateNewMatrix(2,2);

printf("Valeur : %f",GetMatrixValue(m1,1,1));
```

**Edit :**  When I run my code, I had ".exe has stop working" ..

**What did i do wrong ?**

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the most important !

Comment: ".exe has stop working" Did you get an exception thrown ? If yes, what is it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateNewMatrix` returns a `Matrix` not a `Matrix*`

```
struct Matrix* m1 = CreateNewMatrix(2,2);
printf("Valeur : %f",GetMatrixValue(m1,1,1));
```

should be

```
struct Matrix m1 = CreateNewMatrix(2,2);
printf("Valeur : %f",GetMatrixValue(&m1,1,1));
```

You should compile with all warnings on and not run the program until all the warnings go away.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `CreateNewMatrix` to return a struct:

```
struct Matrix CreateNewMatrix(unsigned int n,unsigned int m){
```

But when you use it you expect a pointer to a struct:

```
struct Matrix* m1 = CreateNewMatrix(2,2);
```

This should be a compiler error, though.

Comment: I don't why but i changed the return of CreateNewMatrix from a struct to  pointer and it's now working fine ! Thanks